# Does a woman have to travel to where her husband live for the divorce to happen?

Tags: talaq, travelling

He is in Morocco and I am in the U.S.

If he wants to divorce me, will I have to travel to Morocco for the divorce to happen? Does it have to be face to face?

Comment: No. There is no need for divorce to be face to face. But it has some conditions that you have to observe.

Answer (score 1):

This is feasible for the marriage to be done far from each other but I am not sure regarding the mentioned matter which you asked.

Initially seemingly this is possible to use the lawyer (proxy) for talaq (divorce). Secondly I have heard that this is possible solely for men that without being present … but I am not certain regarding the mentioned matter. So, you’d better to see the following links and hopefully you find your answer there.

- [http://islamquest.net](https://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa8230) and [this](https://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa29299)
- [www.hamvatansalam.com](http://www.hamvatansalam.com/print46464.html)